# Is it possible to simplify $\frac{2^{2x-1} - 2^{x-1}}{2^{2x-1}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Is it possible to simplify this expression?

$\frac{2^{2x-1} - 2^{x-1}}{2^{2x-1}}$

Comment: Try http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+%5Cfrac%7B2%5E%7B2x-1%7D+-+2%5E%7Bx-1%7D%7D%7B2%5E%7B2x-1%7D%7D

Comment: Remember if you ever have a "is it possible" question, try wolfram alpha first!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\frac{2^{2x-1} - 2^{x-1}}{2^{2x-1}}
&=\frac{2^{2x-1}}{2^{2x-1}}-\frac{2^{x-1}}{2^{2x-1}}
\\
&=1-2^{(x-1)-(2x-1)}
\\
&=1-2^{-x}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 6):

Yeah you can do this: $$\frac{ 2^{x-1} \Bigl[ 2^{x}-1\Bigr]}{2^{2x-1}} = \frac{2^{x}-1}{2^{x}}$$

Comment: or $1-2^{-x}$ .